# Jquery Validate & IE Object Expected Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I recently implemented jquery validate on my user login page. Code works great in FF and Chrome, but bombs out in IE 8 & above.

I can't figure out what the issue is so I've finally given in and decided to ask for help

This is the json that is returned -

```
{"REDIRECT_URL":"","ERR_MSG":"Username or password is invalid","ERR_NUM":12}
```

See my submit method below, IE fails inside the $.ajax call on the line where the url param is specificed. The error is `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method`

submitHandler:

```
function(form) {           
    if($("#user_login").valid()){
        var isValidLogin = false;
        var user = $("#username").val();
        var pwd = $("#user_password").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'data_handler.php',
            data: "user=" + user + "&pwd=" + pwd,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                redirect_url = data.REDIRECT_URL;
                err_msg = data.ERR_MSG;

                if(err_msg == ""){
                    location.href = redirect_url;
                            isValidLogin = true;
                }
                else{
                    if(redirect_url != ""){
                        location.href = redirect_url;
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#err_alert').show(); 
                        $('#err_alert').html(err_msg);
                    }

                    isValidLogin = false;
                }
            },
            error:function(){ }
        });

    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line number for the error will help. But in any case you should declare your vars:

```
 success: function (data) {
                var redirect_url = data.REDIRECT_URL;
                var err_msg = data.ERR_MSG;
```

What is probably happening is that the json that is returning does not contain your mentioned properties REDIRECT_URL and/or ERR_MSG.

You can test the json is correct by navigating directly to data_handler.php?user=youruser&pwd=yourpwd

Also Chrome and FF are probably showing the error in the console.

**Update** If the error is on this line:

```
data: "user=" + user + "&pwd=" + pwd,
```

perhaps you should setup a variable above to test it. ie.:

```
var info = "user=" + user + "&pwd=" + pwd;
```

Combined with:

```
data: info,
```

Comment: Thx for the input, the code works fine in Chrome and FF, no errors at all. Fails in IE on the line where the url parameter is set inside the $.ajax call. See below:

url: 'data_handler.php',

Comment: Looks like it was a simple issue of me not declaring those vars like you pointed out!

I declared them and then retested in IE 8,9 & 10 and worked great!

Thanks a ton